# Return a value from client side webservice to Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, web-services

I need to pass a value from client.php to my JavaScript. i have tried so many ways but i could not get what $result in javascript. this is my client side webService code.

```
require 'lib/nusoap.php';
$client = new nusoap_client("http://localhost/DemoWebService/service.php?wsdl");
$result = $client -> call('FunctionName',
        array("UserName" => "$UserName" ,"Password"=>"$Password", "Add"=>"$Add" )     
             );
return  $result ;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass variables and data from PHP to JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-to-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript)

Comment: When  I submit  a login a form (login.htm)  it goes to client.php echo some result which is return by service.php.If I use AJEX  I can get the result in login.html but I want to get the answer in another html page(y.html). Never like to see any result in client.php. Is that possible? Then how?